# difference between uwsgi module in nginx and uwsgi server

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I'm new to linux development. I'm a bit confused on the documentation i read.
My ultimate goal is to host a simple python backed web service that would examine an incoming payload, and forward it to other server. This should be less than 30 lines of code in python.

I'm planning to use nginx to serve up python file. From my research, i also need a python web framework. I chose to go with uwsgi. I'm so confused. which one do I need? an nginx uwsgi module, or uwsgi server? i don't want to put django just for this simple purpose.

the [nginx documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUwsgiModule) mention that

> Do not confuse the uwsgi protocol with the uWSGI server (that speaks the uwsgi protocol)

So, does that mean, i don't need to install uwsgi server separately? do i just install nginx, and start configuring? I'm using nginx 1.4.4

Could someone share a step by step configuration procedure on how to configure uwsgi with nginx, along with a sample python code(hello world maybe)? i can configure nginx just fine, but i don't know how to make it serve python pages. all the docs i could find involves having django on top.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're mixing up things, so let me clarify.

Python's standard way of publishing applications via web servers is [**WSGI**](https://wsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)--you can think of it as a Python's native CGI. [**uWSGI**](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/) is a WSGI-compliant server that uses **uwsgi** protocol to talk to other uWSGI instances or upstream servers. Usually the upstream server is [**nginx**](http://nginx.org/) with **HttpUwsgiModule** that allows it to communicate using uwsgi protocol--with nginx you have additional layer of protection for your app server, load balancing and serving the static files. In most scenarios, [You Should Be Using Nginx + UWSGI](http://cra.mr/2013/06/27/serving-python-web-applications). To answer your question, uWSGI is installed and run separately from nginx, and they both need to be configured to communicate to each other.

Pure WSGI is pretty low-level, so you may want to use a WSGI-compliant [**framework**](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/frameworks.html). I guess the top two are [**Django**](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [**Flask**](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

For a hello world Flask setup, [Serving Flask With Nginx](http://vladikk.com/2013/09/12/serving-flask-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/) seems to be a good article.

Comment: can the apache mod_wsgi talk to nginx using the uwsgi protocol ? @jwalker

Comment: @deepak You answered your own question: it's for Apache. There used to be mod_wsgi for nginx, but you really don't want that.

Comment: actually my question was can uwsgi protocol be used between the nginx and apache @jwalker

Comment: @deepak I don't think so. Why would you need that?

Comment: [You Should Be Using Nginx + UWSGI](http://justcramer.com/2013/06/27/serving-python-web-applications/) is broken

Comment: @fujianjin6471 fixed