# What is the difference between mod_wsgi and uwsgi?

Tags: python, apache, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

There seems to be mod_wsgi module in Apache and uwsgi module in Nginx. And there also seems to be the wsgi protocol and uwsgi protocol.

I have the following questions.

1. Are mod_wsgi and uwsgi just different implementations to provide WSGI capabilities to the Python web developer?
2. Is there a mod_wsgi for Nginx?
3. Does uwsgi also offer the `application(environ, start_response)` entry point to the developers?
4. Is uwsgi also a separate protocol apart from wsgi? In this case, how is the uwsgi protocol different from the wsgi protocol?

Comment: Wolph is right, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20628400/1914052) should also help.

Comment: The badly named mod_wsgi for nginx is not in any way related to the mod_wsgi for Apache as far as authorship and code base. The mod_wsgi for nginx also has various drawbacks because of how nginx works. Read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2009/05/blocking-requests-and-nginx-version-of.html and find out why it may not be that great of an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. They are just 2 different ways of running WSGI applications.
2. Have you tried googling for `mod_wsgi nginx`?
3. Any wsgi compliant server has that entry point, that's what the wsgi specification requires.
4. Yes, but that's only how `uwsgi` communicates with Nginx. With `mod_wsgi` the Python part is run from within Nginx, with `uwsgi` you run a separate app.

Comment: @lapinrigolo: partially correct, the point was that a quick Google would tell you that. For nginx I generally use gunicorn and sometimes uwsgi. The latter is more of a hassle than its worth generally though. There have been efforts for a nginx mod_wsgi but they're not really in production state.