# Why I should use uwsgi with flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

For example I have some web application based on Flask that runs on 5000 port and some front web-server(nginx) that runs on 80 port.

Why I should configure and use uWSGI module instead of simple:

```
$ python ./app.py
```

and

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000
}
```

?

Comment: there is no answer

Comment: Flask built-in server should not be used in production, the fact that you put it behind nginx doesn't really change anything, the flask server is still the bottleneck.

Comment: Please refer to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20628400/1965509